# Fortran, ISO C BINDING and std::string

Tags: c++, fortran, fortran-iso-c-binding

I have a c++ method with the signature

```
extern std::string os_dtoa_format(double  x);
```

that I would like to call from Fortran. I understand that I have to build an explicit interface, but I am not really sure how to go about that. I have a vague idea of how to handle the double, but I have not found anything about the std::string. char* seems difficult enough, which leads me to ask whether it is even possible to do what I want.

Comment: Passing `double` between Fortran and C++ shouldn't be an issue since C++ and Fortran have appropriate types for it. With strings there are some issues: 1) raw strings in C++ implemented as zero-terminated array of chars, and in Fortran strings are pair of (not zero-terminated) array of chars and length of the string; 2) When returning `std::string` you pass *copy* of C++ object, so it's constructors and destructors should be called in time (about which Fortran has no idea); 3) Fortran can't free memory that is allocated for string in C++ runtime.

Answer (score 6):

There are a couple of ways of arranging this, the following just explores one possibility.  In addition to providing an extern "C" wrapper function around the C++ function that you want to be able to call from Fortran, this example also uses a small Fortran procedure to be called from C++ in order to actually copy the data in the std::string result across to a Fortran character variable.  It is robust to variation between the working real kind and character kind on the fortran side being different to C_DOUBLE and C_CHAR respectively.

The C++ code:

```
#include <string>

// The function returning a std::string that you wish to call from Fortran.
std::string os_dtoa_format(double x);
// Utility provided via Fortran code to copy a C string to a deferred length 
// allocatable component of an object nominated by the fstring_ptr pointer.
extern "C" void set_fortran_string(void* fstring_ptr, int length, const char* str);

// A wrapper for the Fortran code to call.
extern "C" void os_dtoa_format_wrapper(double x, void* fstring_ptr)
{
   std::string s = os_dtoa_format(x);
   set_fortran_string(fstring_ptr, s.size(), s.c_str());
}
```

The fortran code

```
MODULE os_dtoa_format_module
  ! Access the  real and character kinds being used in the Fortran code.
  USE Kinds, ONLY: rk, ck
  IMPLICIT NONE
  ! Type to wrap a deferred length component such that it can be passed 
  ! through the C++ code.
  TYPE FString
    CHARACTER(KIND=ck,LEN=:), ALLOCATABLE :: item
  END TYPE FString
CONTAINS
  ! Function for Fortran client code to call to invoke the C++ 
  ! function of interest.
  FUNCTION os_dtoa_format_fortran(x) RESULT(str)
    USE, INTRINSIC :: ISO_C_BINDING, ONLY: C_DOUBLE, C_LOC
    REAL(rk), INTENT(IN) :: x
    CHARACTER(KIND=ck,LEN=:), ALLOCATABLE :: str
    INTERFACE
      ! Interface of the interoperable extern "C" C++ wrapper.
      SUBROUTINE os_dtoa_format_wrapper(x, fstring_ptr)  &
          BIND(C, NAME='os_dtoa_format_wrapper')
        USE, INTRINSIC :: ISO_C_BINDING, ONLY: C_DOUBLE, C_PTR
        IMPLICIT NONE
        REAL(C_DOUBLE), INTENT(IN), VALUE :: x
        TYPE(C_PTR), INTENT(IN), VALUE :: fstring_ptr
      END SUBROUTINE 
    END INTERFACE
    ! Object used to pass the deferred length componnt through the 
    ! C++ code.
    TYPE(FString), TARGET :: f_str
    !****
    ! Call the C++ wrapper, perhaps converting the real kind.  Also 
    ! pass the asddress of the object with the deferred length 
    ! component.
    CALL os_dtoa_format_wrapper(REAL(x, C_DOUBLE), C_LOC(f_str))
    ! Move the deferred length string into the function result.
    CALL MOVE_ALLOC(f_str%item, str)
  END FUNCTION os_dtoa_format_fortran

  ! Utility function to be called from C/C++ to copy a char array 
  ! (a C string) into a Fortran allocatable deferred length 
  ! character component.
  SUBROUTINE set_fortran_string(fstring_ptr, length, str)  &
      BIND(C, NAME='set_fortran_string')
    USE, INTRINSIC :: ISO_C_BINDING, ONLY:  &
        C_PTR, C_CHAR, C_INT, C_F_POINTER
    ! The C address of the object that holds the deferred length 
    ! character component.
    TYPE(C_PTR), INTENT(IN), VALUE :: fstring_ptr
    ! The length of the char array.
    INTEGER(C_INT), INTENT(IN), VALUE :: length
    ! The char array.
    CHARACTER(KIND=C_CHAR), INTENT(IN) :: str(length)
    ! Fortran pointer to the object referenced by fstring_ptr that 
    ! holds the deferred length character component.
    TYPE(FString), POINTER :: f_str
    ! Declare type of the string index (F2003 doesn't allow inline 
    ! type declaration in a forall header - F2008 does).
    INTEGER :: i
    !****
    ! Associate the Fortran pointer with the object referenced by the 
    ! C address.
    CALL C_F_POINTER(fstring_ptr, f_str)
    ! Allocate the deferred length component to the given length.
    ALLOCATE(CHARACTER(length) :: f_str%item)
    ! Copy over the data.
    FORALL (i=1:length) f_str%item(i:i) = str(i)
  END SUBROUTINE set_fortran_string
END MODULE os_dtoa_format_module
```